# How to increase mouse pointer size in X410 on WSL2?

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, mouse-cursor

I've got X410 running on my Windows 10 system. I've got a 4k screen on the laptop and another 4k attached to it. I've bumped up the Windows cursor sizes just to make it easy to find my mouse.

However in my Ubuntu 20.04 WSL2 install both alacritty and emacs have a very small pointer. Would love to bump up the size of the pointer. (It doesn't even have to be big, just normal size, right now they are tiny). Installing big-cursor on Ubuntu didn't help.

Comment: Try: (1) `sudo apt-get update -y` and `sudo apt-get install -y big-cursor`, (2) `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-size 32` where: 24: Default, 32: Medium, 48: Large, 64: Larger, 96: Largest.